ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datachain.lib'; 'datachain' is not a package

Why am I encountering the ModuleNotFoundError for the datachain.lib module?
Are there any additional steps I need to take to properly use the datachain package in my project?

I'm working on a Python project and I encountered the following error when trying to import a module:
import os
os.environ["PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION"] = "python"
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from datachain.lib.dc import Column, DataChain

Error Message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datachain.lib'; 'datachain' is not a package

Details:

I've installed datachain using pip: pip install datachain.
The installed version of datachain is 0.2.18 as shown by running pip list.
I have verified that the package is correctly installed and located in my Python environment.


did you name your file datachain.py ?

There are some things you could check to see where exactly is the problem. What environment manager do you use? If you are using Conda for example make sure you have your env active when trying to run code. Using virtual env with Conda worked fine for me so this should solve the issues.
Here are some long shots that you might try:

Check the structure of you project. It does seem like the whole 'datachain' is not being found as library but this might be useful to see if structure is like you have in your imports.

I had this problem some years ago on one of my old machines when I wasn't using any env manager that some libraries would be a problem to run after some time. Meaning that everything would be just saved with ´pip install x´ to the same env. Again pointing to use of virtual envs to solve the issue


